# Typescript type inference algorithm for conditional types

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I would like to learn the algorithm by which Typescript attempts to infer types in signatures using conditional types.

**Example 1:** here we correctly infer `T` as `number`:

```js
type Args<T> = { value: T }

function foo<T>(args: Args<T>) { return args; }

// correctly inferred as foo<number>
foo({ value: 123 });
```

**Example 2:** conditional types and inferring `unknown`

```js
type StringOrNever<T> = T extends string ? string : never;
type Args<T> = { value: StringOrNever<T>; }

function foo<T>(args: Args<T>) { return args; }

// both calls inferred as foo<unknown> :(
foo({ value: 123 });
foo({ value: "some string" });
```

**Example 3:** correct (or "expected") inference but weird types

```js
type StringOrNever<T> = T extends string ? string : never;
type Args<T> = { value: StringOrNever<T> & T; }

function foo<T>(args: Args<T>) { return args; }

// inferred as foo<number>
foo({ value: 123 });

// inferred as foo<"Typescript">
foo({ value: "Typescript" });
```

What I would like to learn is:

1. Why does Typescript infer `unknown` for `T` in example 2, and what exactly causes it to infer types for `T` as I expect in example (3)
2. If there is some general algorithm which Typescript follows to try to infer a generic type argument. Like for example trying a sequence of candidates, in which first candidate is always a type of argument and the last candidate is `unknown` (kinda like a last resort).

Comment: Well in your third example there's an error as expected, because `never & number` is reduced to `never`, and you get "Type number is not assignable to never".

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://tsplay.dev/mqkxkw) magical narrowing type?

Comment: @kelly this type for sure looks magical! Thanks!
However, what I'm looking for is the explanation on why TSC resolves a generic argument in the way it does :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A generic type inference is a complicated and sometimes hard to understand concept in TypeScript. But the generic type must be used in a position where it can be substituted by a type of the given argument.

So for example 1

```
function foo<T>(args: { value: T }) { return args; }
```

if you pass a value of type `{ value: string }`, we can substitute `T` with `string`.

The same can not be said about example 2.

```
type StringOrNever<T> = T extends string ? string : never;

function foo<T>(args: { value: StringOrNever<T> }) { return args; }
```

`T` is only used in the comparison part of the condtional. On the right side of the conditional we only have `string` and `never`. `T` is not in any place which could be substituted by the given type, so `unknown` is inferred as the default type.

If you want inference to succed, you will need to put `T` on the right side of the conditional.

```
type StringOrNever<T> = T extends string ? T : never;

function foo<T>(args: { value: StringOrNever<T> }) { return args; }
```

This allows TypeScript to infer `T` based on the given type of `value`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysBOBLAdgcwPLwHIQG4XgB4AVAPigF4pioIAPYCZAEwGcpWEVUoB%20aqAC4oyPAQDcAWABQoSFACC8VKxLkqAbyi4AhgBsArhGFwkaTDnxEy4qAF8ZMgGYHkAY2CIA9sihOvXmoAFDrKrMJKKmoAlFBa8BDABvC%20oSq2DtIyAPTZUABGXsAAFlBu%20nrsKE4ECcxQOuz%20ga4A1sheAO7I5IJBzgFBWrqGxlAAjABMAMz20VLSzUPa%20kbCAESsXgC20JxmqOtz4kA)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!
Could you elaborate a bit on what "can be substituted"  means?

For example, if we set `StringOrNever<T> = T extends string ? T : never`, then in the third example if we call `foo({ value: 123 })` it will infer `T` as number, but there will also be an error about function signature -- since `T` is inferred as number, type of `value` would need to be `never & number === never`

So, what was the reason that TS picked `number` and not `unknown` for inference here? Both would result in the same error

Comment: @so_close - It can pick up `number` is the inferred type because `T` is on the right side of the conditional. But it also performs the `T extends string` check and evaluates to `never`. The logic is a bit backwards here, as TypeScript does the inference first and then does the conditional.

Comment: So, is the rule like "Whenever `T` is on the right hand side of the conditional, infer `T` as the argument type"?

Comment: I'll mark this as an answer. If you'd like to edit your answer to provide additional clarification in spite of my comments, I'd be really grateful :)

Comment: @so_close - Sorry I missed your last comment. I can't really go into the details of the algorithm behind all of this since I have no clue what the compiler does internally. But for the simple case where `T` is on the right side of the conditional in the true branch, it is used for inference. This may or may not be true for more complex cases though.